# How to make a series of parallel API requests with dynamic parameters in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, rest, express

I want to make a series of API calls with changing a single parameter value in the URL based on parameter values stored in an array (About 30-40 values). I'm using NodeJS and Express. Following is a snippet I wrote for this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var rest = require('restler');

router.get('/myroute', function(req, res, next){
    parameterArray = [ /* A list of parameter values in here gathered from two more API calls */];
    returnArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < parameterArray.length; i++){
        var url = 'https://api.example.org?parameter=' + parameterArray[i];
        rest.get(url).on('success', function(data){
          // after some processing on data
          returnArray.push(processedData);
        });
    }

    res.json(returnArray);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have two questions:

1.) Currently `router.get('/myroute')` take about 40-50 seconds to finish and return. How would I make them faster? I have looked at [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads). Are there any better options?

2.) In the code above, the router function `router.get('/myroute')` returns `returnArray` empty as `restler` makes asynchronous calls. How can I make sure that the function returns only after it has received all API requests (and pushed processed data into the `returnArray`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) this heavily depends on the response of your ajax calls (network traffic and server processing on the other end), so not sure if you can really speed up much with multiple threads.

2) rest.get() is an async call. Using regular for loop will not work because it won't wait for all ajax calls to finish.  That's why returnArray is empty.  You can use async.each() (process in parallel), but I'd suggest you use async.eachLimit() so you can throttle the number of ajax calls.  Flushing 30-40 of those to your server might not be a good idea if your server can't handle that many transactions simultaneously.  Here is the revised code (note that I throttle ajax calls to 5 at a time, you can play with this number to see what's best for you):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var rest = require('restler');
var async = require('async');

router.get('/myroute', function(req, res, next){
    var parameterArray = [ /* A list of parameter values in here gathered from two more API calls */];
    var returnArray = [];

    async.eachLimit(parameterArray, 5, function(param, eachCb) {
        var url = 'https://api.example.org?parameter=' + param;
        rest.get(url).on('complete', function(data){
            var processedData;
            // after some processing on data
            returnArray.push(processedData);
            eachCb(null);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        // done with all ajax calls
        res.json(returnArray);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. What I meant as API calls taking about 40s to return is actually the time taken by `router.get('/myroute')` as a whole. I've edited the question. Also, could you tell me what eachCb is? Thanks again.

Comment: async.each()'s callback.  Rather than name it just 'callback', eachCb is a bit meaningful, by looking at the code, I know right away where this callback is coming from.  Otherwise, when you have nested async calls, just 'callback' for all nested async calls' callbacks will be kind of confusing.